# Compression function in Postgres

Tags: postgresql, jdbc, compression

Using Java & JDBC I am storing Strings into a JSONB column in Postgres.  When inserting this works great.

When retrieving values, I am running low on memory in Java because I am retrieving larger quantities and each json/string is about 1MB.  What I would like to do is write a query like this:

```
SELECT compress( myJsonColumn ) FROM myTable WHERE ...
```

I have looked around a bit for a compress method in Postgres, but haven't found one.  Any pointers would be appreciated.  Thanks.

Clarification: Just to be clear, I don't want to compress the data in the database.  I think that Postgres will handle this gracefully, my concern is mostly java-heap-space.

I have three components in my architecture.

1. Clients who need the uncompressed json (and who will handle the uncompression themselves)
2. A Service that serves multiple clients.  I am trying to protect the service's memory.  The service never needs to see the uncompressed json.
3. The DB.  I want to store the json in a jsonb field, not as binary so that I can write new queries against the data later if required.

[image]

Comment: Sounds like an X-Y problem to me. What are you planning to do with compressed strings? You'll still have to uncompress them to parse/display/whatever.

Comment: I'm voting to close this because it's unclear what you're asking. How does compressing json to have it uncompressed by Java save you space on the heap? I agree with @mustaccio here.

Comment: If you are concerned about heap space, you could do the compression in Java. The intermediate objects from the ResultSet will be collected pretty quickly anyways.

Comment: Check out https://github.com/grahamedgecombe/pgflate but also see first if using a server-side cursor to fetch one row at a time wouldn't better address the memory problem.

Comment: @EvanCarroll - Updated question to answer your question.

Comment: @mustaccio - Updated to answer your question.

Comment: How do you get the uncompressed json to the client, if you want the service to see the compressed json? That's the question we're all asking that we don't understand. @sixtyfootersdude

Comment: @EvanCarroll - The server sends the compressed json to the client.  The client uncompresses the json.  I am concerned that if my server handles the json with out compression that it will run out of memory because the json is quite large.  Compressed the json becomes 10% of the size.

Answer (score 5):

I've recently had the occasion to use something like this:

```
CREATE FUNCTION gzip(text) RETURNS bytea
    LANGUAGE plperlu IMMUTABLE STRICT COST 100000 PARALLEL SAFE
    AS $_X$
    use Compress::Zlib;
    my $x = Compress::Zlib::memGzip($_[0]);
    return encode_bytea($x);
$_X$;
```

But note that bytea is itself transmitted in an escaped form which will enlarge the size.  With any luck, JDBC implementation might unescape them on the fly as they are read into memory, and not store the entire result set in the raw form.  Sorry, I don't use JDBC enough to know.

Can't you just use a cursor to process one row at a time and then discard it, rather than reading all rows into memory?

Comment: That's not thread safe, and probably shouldn't be marked so. `Compress::Zlib` uses `Compress::Raw::Zlib` which has an [open bug about thread safety](https://rt.cpan.org/Public/Bug/Display.html?id=102110). I don't see the benefit of this at all: if you're trying to save on transit use a vpn with compression. If you're trying to save space in the DB -- it's toasted automagically after 2kb. And, I don't see how having to uncompress this with zlib will result in less space on Java's heap (from the OP) looking to save "mostly java-heap-space"

Comment: PARALLEL SAFE is not about thread safety, as postgresql is not multi-threaded.  If you read multiple rows as compressed data into memory, and then uncompress them one at a time in one Java and discard, it will use less memory.

Comment: It is not multithreaded.  It uses separate processes, not threads, to achieve parallelism.